# Unable to download anything from apt-cacher-ng proxy

Tags: apt, proxy, apt-cacher-ng, apt-cacher

I have installed `apt-cacher-ng` on my server. There are about 10 clients which will use this proxy to download the packages. Things were working fine since many days, however, all of sudden I started facing a lot of issues.

While downloading package, I'm facing following issue:

```
Err http://192.168.10.167 precise/main Sources
Unable to connect to 10.10.163.162:3142:*
```

Removing all contents from `/var/cache/apt-cacher-ng` and restarting server helped me to resolve the issue for a few hours. But issue starts popping up again after few hours.

I can see following errors in my `/var/log/apt-cacher-ng/apt-cacher.err`

```
Thu Feb 26 09:59:00 2015|known **data hit, don't write to...**
Thu Feb 26 09:59:00 2015|/var/cache/apt-cacher-ng/192.168.10.167/images/dists/ug/unstable/binary-i386/Packages.gz
Thu Feb 26 09:05:03 2015|gce.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/i18n/Translation-en storage error [503 Cache storage error - Too many open files]: **Too many open files**
Thu Feb 26 09:05:04 2015|Error creating pipe file descriptors
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: try to check your hard drive space with `df -h`, may be you haven't any free space

Comment: I do have lot of free space (around 900 GB is free)

Comment: for the problem of `Too many open files` you should verify your hard and soft limit. try this command `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` and tell me the result

Comment: cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
1529212

Comment: hard drive seems ok, check please the hard and soft limit

Comment: ps aux | grep your_program ; cat /proc/pid_of_your_program/limits

Comment: Can you please tell me that what should I substitute for "your_program"

Comment: take a look in here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-cacher-ng/+bug/572095

Comment: with apt-cacher-ng

Comment: Max open files   soft-limit:1024   hard-limit:4096

Comment: I think just in workarround you can increase of limit because you have a lot of file opened and you have execceeded limits

Comment: Can you please tell me that how can I increase this limit?

Comment: check my response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can increase limits like this:

edit file /etc/security/limits.conf

```
# vi /etc/security/limits.conf
```

Set program_user soft and hard limits as follows:

```
program_user soft nofile 4096
program_user hard nofile 10240
```

Save and close config file. Check limits, try this:

```
# su - program_user
$ ulimit -Hn
$ ulimit -Sn
```

Comment: I saw your answer little late. I followed below link
http://gregchapple.com/updating-ulimit-on-running-linux-process/

Is that correct?

Comment: *         hard    nofile      500000
*         soft    nofile      500000

Comment: That doesn't apply to `upstart` scripts (which someone might still use) as pointed out at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995855/increase-max-open-files-for-ubuntu-upstart-initctl posted by @TahirRauf below.

Answer (score 1):

For increasing the "maximum open files" limit of apt-cacher-ng, I just did the following.

In /etc/init.d/apt-cacher-ng, I added:

```
limit nofile 50000 50000
```

Please see following links for further details:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995855/increase-max-open-files-for-ubuntu-upstart-initctl
- [http://bryanmarty.com/2012/02/10/setting-nofile-limit-upstart/](http://web.archive.org/web/20190422104551/http://bryanmarty.com/2012/02/10/setting-nofile-limit-upstart/)